# Two dice conditional probability

Tags: probability

Two dice are thrown at the same time. We know that one of them is 4. What is the probability of the other be two?

I know  that the first solution is correct, but why is the second one incorrect?

Solution 1. I consider the sample state as $$S=\{(1,4),(2,4)(3,4),(4,4),(5,4),(6,4),(4,1),(4,2),(4,3),(4,5),(4,6)\}$$
$$A=\{(2,4),(4,2)\}$$
then
$P(A)=\frac{n(A)}{n(S)}=\frac{2}{11}$

Solution 2. Consider $S$ be sample state of all possible events in rolling 2 dices, $n(S)=36$.
$$P(A)=P(\text{other }2\mid\text{one dice }4)=P((1\text{st } 2\mid 2\text{nd } 4)\text{or}(2\text{nd }  2\mid 1\text{st }4))$$
$$=P(1\text{st } 2\mid2\text{nd } 4)+P(2\text{nd }  2\mid1\text{st }4)-P((1\text{st } 2\mid2\text{nd } 4)\text{and}(2\text{nd }  2\mid1\text{st }4))$$
$$=\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{36}=\frac{11}{36}$$
Or
$$=P(1\text{st } 2\mid 2\text{nd } 4)+P(2\text{nd }  2\mid 1\text{st }4)=\frac{1}{3}$$

Comment: Shouldn't it just be 1/6? These are independent events, right?

Comment: First, $\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{36}$ is not  $\frac{1}{3}$. The result for "solution 2" should be   $\frac{11}{36}$. Which, by the way, is exactly the probability of geting at least one 2 when throwing two dices at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've made a conceptual error, not a calculation error. In the second method, you have treated $(1\text{st } 2\mid 2\text{nd } 4) \,\,$ and $\,\,(2\text{nd }  2\mid 1\text{st }4)$ as if they are events which can have an union or an intersection, which can both occur or not both occur, etc, in other words, as events that live in the same sample space. But they do not.

Suppose we call $\Omega$ the original sample space with $36$ outcomes. The confusing thing (when you're first getting acquainted with the subject) is that while  $(1\text{st } 2\mid 2\text{nd } 4) \,\,$ and $\,\,(2\text{nd }  2\mid 1\text{st }4)$ are both subsets of $\Omega$, they're conditioned on different things, so they actually live in different probability spaces. That's why you can't use inclusion/exclusion to calculate the probability of $(1\text{st } 2\mid 2\text{nd } 4) \,\, \bigcup \,\,(2\text{nd }  2\mid 1\text{st }4)$. The probability function that eats things like $(1\text{st } 2\mid 2\text{nd } 4)$ is a completely different probability function than the one that eats things like $(2\text{nd }  2\mid 1\text{st }4)$. So you can no longer do the same tricks with probabilities of their union, intersection, etc.

More concretely, you overcounted the probability because by separating into the two cases, you treated it as if we rolled twice, and the first time we knew that the second die was a four and the second time we knew that the first die was a four, and as if we were looking for the probability that we get a two and a four exactly once. But that's not the information we have, of course.

You could accurately calculate
$$\mathbb{P}(2 \text{ and } 4 \mid \text{ One is a }4) = \mathbb{P} (2 \text{ and } 4 \mid \text{ First is }4) \cdot \mathbb{P}(\text{First is a }4 \mid \text{ One is a }4)$$
$$ + \mathbb{P} (2 \text{ and } 4 \mid \text{ First is not a }4) \cdot \mathbb{P}(\text{First is not a }4 \mid \text{ One is a }4)$$
$$= \frac16 \cdot \frac{6}{11} + \frac{1}{5}\cdot \frac{5}{11}= \frac{2}{11}.$$